# iOS clear push notifications

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I notice that for apps like Google Hangout, Facebook etc. when I get a push notification for any event (people writing on my wall, etc.), if I view the event on my desktop, it will clear the push notification (which I have not cleared myself or opened the app for) on my iPhone.

How can I implement the same?

Right now i'm using [this](https://github.com/stephenmuss/django-ios-notifications) app for implementing my push's.

I customized the above, but the implementation is similar. Do I need to send any special data to the phone to clear all notifications from my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did same in my application that read notifications don't remain in Application. Buts its not how you think it is.

i Saved Remote `Notification` in method `didReceiveRemoteNotification:` in DataBase (Coredata).
Everytime i was in `NotificationViewController` i retrieved from DataBase (Coredata) and when i want to clear them i-e on Reading , deleted that particular Notification form DB.

thats how you should do it.

OR https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS7.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013162-SW1 Apple says in iOS 7 user can send "silent" push notifications—that is, notifications that do not display alerts or otherwise disturb the user. By receieving this type "silent" in method `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` do this `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 0]; [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];`

Comment: Hmm... But seems like when Google and Facebook do it, they do it without me even touching the app. I'm on the lock screen--and I can see the notifications going away. That core data handling only works when the app is open as far as I know?

Comment: You want to do it when you select a particular Row in UITable ?

Comment: No. I see push notifications on my lock screen. When I do something on the website, the push notifications on my lock screen disappear. That's how it was implemented in these other platforms.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS7.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013162-SW1 says in iOS 7 user can send "silent" push notifications—that is, notifications that do not display alerts or otherwise disturb the user. By receieving this type "silent" in method application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: do this 

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 0];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

Comment: I don't think this is for a silent push. I'm talking about clearing all of the current push notifications which haven't been clicked on.

Comment: The function you are referring to only gets called when the user interacts with that notification

Comment: You cannot interact Silent notifications. but in `didReceiveRemoteNotification:` you can clear/cancel every Notification. You just need to check if Notification is silent then do this `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 0]; [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];`

Answer (score 2):

Just ask your backend to send a push with the payload:

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "badge" : 0
    },
}
```